# Gatsby: Transforming data returned from a page query at build time

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

For example, I want to flatten an array of lists returned by the query at **build time** before it is available to the page component, *ie*, without having to do it client side on every request.
Is there a lifecycle method or middleware where this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is one of the things I appreciate most about the GraphQL data layer in Gatsby. There are a slew of APIs available for transforming data nodes, including adding new ones based on type, all before your page queries are run. This means you can create new structures that match your needs precisely, then fetch the fields from those structures to feed your page components, and the results of those queries will end up in your page-data.json files without any trace of the source.

### `onCreateNode` ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode))

> Called when a new node is created. Plugins wishing to extend or transform nodes created by other plugins should implement this API.
>
> ```js
> exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions }) => {
>   const { createNode, createNodeField } = actions
>     // Transform the new node here and create a new node or
>     // create a new node field.
> }
> ```

`createNodeField` ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/actions/#createNodeField))

> Extend another node. The new node field is placed under the fields key on the extended node object.
>
> Once a plugin has claimed a field name the field name can’t be used by other plugins. Also since nodes are immutable, you can’t mutate the node directly. So to extend another node, use this.
>
> ```js
> createNodeField({
>   node,
>   name: `happiness`,
>   value: `is sweet graphql queries`
> })
> ```

### `createResolvers` ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#createResolvers))

> Add custom field resolvers to the GraphQL schema.
>
> Allows adding new fields to types by providing field configs, or adding resolver functions to existing fields.
>
> ```js
> exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
>   const resolvers = {
>     Author: {
>       fullName: {
>         resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
>           return source.firstName + source.lastName
>         }
>       },
>     },
>     Query: {
>       allRecentPosts: {
>         type: [`BlogPost`],
>         resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
>           const posts = context.nodeModel.getAllNodes({ type: `BlogPost` })
>           const recentPosts = posts.filter(
>             post => post.publishedAt > Date.UTC(2018, 0, 1)
>           )
>           return recentPosts
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   createResolvers(resolvers)
> }
> ```